# Countdown Timer Not Working with the Video Background (Shopify)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, shopify

I'm adding a countdown timer with the background video, but timer is not showing.
I notice when I used Incognito the timer will show for the first time and after I refresh my page the countdown timer is missing and I inspect element I have this error  *Query.Deferred exception: $.lofCountDown is not a constructor TypeError: $.lofCountDown is not a constructor*

link:https://strokes-test.myshopify.com/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOLD4.jpg)

**SNIPPET**

```
{% capture currentProducID %}{{ section.settings.title }}@{% endcapture %}
{% if dealPro contains currentProducID %}
{% assign dealProTime = dealPro | replace: currentProducID,'' | replace: '_',' ' %}
<div class="deal-clock lof-clock-{{ section.settings.title}}-detail"></div>
<script>
  !function(){$.fn.lofCountDown=function(t){return this.each(function(){new $.lofCountDown(this,t)})},$.lofCountDown=function(t,e){if(this.options=$.extend({autoStart:!0,LeadingZero:!0,DisplayFormat:"<div>%%D%% Days</div><div>%%H%% Hours</div><div>%%M%% Minutes</div><div>%%S%% Seconds</div>",FinishMessage:"Expired",CountActive:!0,TargetDate:null},e||{}),null!=this.options.TargetDate&&""!=this.options.TargetDate){this.timer=null,this.element=t,this.CountStepper=-1,this.CountStepper=Math.ceil(this.CountStepper),this.SetTimeOutPeriod=1e3*(Math.abs(this.CountStepper)-1)+990;var n=new Date(this.options.TargetDate),i=new Date;this.CountStepper>0?ddiff=new Date(i-n):ddiff=new Date(n-i),gsecs=Math.floor(ddiff.valueOf()/1e3),this.CountBack(gsecs,this)}},$.lofCountDown.fn=$.lofCountDown.prototype,$.lofCountDown.fn.extend=$.lofCountDown.extend=$.extend,$.lofCountDown.fn.extend({calculateDate:function(t,e,n){var i=(Math.floor(t/e)%n).toString();return this.options.LeadingZero&&i.length<2&&(i="0"+i),"<b>"+i+"</b>"},CountBack:function(t,e){return 0>t?void(e.element.innerHTML='<div class="lof-labelexpired"> '+e.options.FinishMessage+"</div>"):(clearInterval(e.timer),DisplayStr=e.options.DisplayFormat.replace(/%%D%%/g,e.calculateDate(t,86400,1e5)),DisplayStr=DisplayStr.replace(/%%H%%/g,e.calculateDate(t,3600,24)),DisplayStr=DisplayStr.replace(/%%M%%/g,e.calculateDate(t,60,60)),DisplayStr=DisplayStr.replace(/%%S%%/g,e.calculateDate(t,1,60)),e.element.innerHTML=DisplayStr,void(e.options.CountActive&&(e.timer=null,e.timer=setTimeout(function(){e.CountBack(t+e.CountStepper,e)},e.SetTimeOutPeriod))))}})}(jQuery);

  //<![CDATA[
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".lof-clock-{{ section.settings.title }}-detail").lofCountDown({
      TargetDate:"{{ dealProTime }}",
      DisplayFormat:"<ul class='list-inline'><li class='day'>%%D%%<span>Days</span></li><li class='hours'>%%H%%<span>Hours</span></li><li class='mins'>%%M%%<span>Mins</span></li><li class='seconds'>%%S%%<span>Secs</span></li></ul>",
      FinishMessage: ""
      });
  });
  //]]>
</script>
<style></style>
{% break %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

**SECTION**

```
  {% if section.settings.vid_link != blank %}
  <video class="herovid-desktop" width="100%" playsinline loop muted autoplay>
    <source src="{{ section.settings.vid_link }}" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  {% endif %}
  <!-- video hero mobile -->
  {% if section.settings.vid_link_mobile != blank %}
  <video class="herovid-mobile" width="100%" playsinline loop muted autoplay>
    <source src="{{ section.settings.vid_link_mobile }}" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  {% endif %}
</div>
  
   {% if section.settings.title != blank %}
   <div class="products">
    <div class="products-container">
    {% if settings.count_down_collections %}
      {% assign dealTime = settings.home_productdeal_time | split: ' ' | join: ' ' | split: ' ' %}
      <h1> {% include 'countdown-for-video-hero' %}</h1>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
    </div>
      {% endif %}
{% schema %}
  {
    "name": "Video-Hero",
    "settings": 
[
    {
        "label": "Title",
        "id": "title",
        "type": "text"
    },
    {
        "type":"text",
        "id":"vid_link",
        "label":"Video Desktop Link"
    },
    {
        "type":"text",
        "id":"vid_link_mobile",
        "label":"Video Mobile Link"
    }
],
"presets":
[
    {
        "name":"Video-Hero",
        "category":"Custom Sections"
    }
]
    }
{% endschema %}

{% stylesheet %}
{% endstylesheet %}

{% javascript %}
{% endjavascript %}
```

Comment: sorry, but now it not working on the desktop as well.

Comment: @Onkar its working on my side https://strokes-test.myshopify.com/

Comment: https://prnt.sc/10bv09b

Comment: @Onkar I noticed when I used Incognito it will load for the first time but when I refresh the page it will be gone.

Comment: It works well when the full jQuery lib is added to the theme, I think there is 2 jQuery versions are into your time and it conflicts with each other, there is jquery-slim.js added in the header and another is added into theme files, I think you need to sort this conflict and it works well.

Comment: Ok I gonna check that, but its weird the countdown looks fine on my slider but on video I have some conflicts.

Comment: I think need some CSS code to update the design to look like this one: https://prnt.sc/10c1eu8

Comment: Yes like that I change the code, how can manage that look?? sorry Im bad at CSS LOL

Comment: https://gist.github.com/o-nkar/7897e683b63a8591ca2ad31883c2a6f7, add it to the end of your CSS file.